# Changing style of Component inside NavLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-props

I am making a navbar, using NavLink from React-Router-Dom. Using 'isActive' prop to style the active Link, is okay.
But, how could I style the subelements inside of it.
To be exact, please see this ...

```
const Nav = [
{path : '/', icon : <NavIcon.Home />},
{path : '/service', icon : <NavIcon.Service />}
]

function someFunc(){
return (
Nav.map(({path, icon}) => (
<NavLink key={path} to ={path}>
{icon} //this icon is actually an svg icon and i want to change its 'fill' attr. conditionally, when the navLink is active or not. I am using .ts
</NavLink>
))}
}

const Home = () => {
<svg ....other attributes ....  fill ={isActive ? 'color1' : 'color2'}> //I want this fill to be conditional so based on as to link is active or not. (**this svg exists into different component, as so do the NavLink**).
...
</svg>
}
```

how should I use 'isActive' from navLink inside of my svg component? and connect to 'isActive' inside of  inside of entirely different component?

ps : - I TRIED making interface type in svg component as

```
interface Props extends NavLinkProps {
isActive : boolean;
}

const Home = ({isActive} : Props) => {
return (
<svg fill ={isActive ? 'color1' : 'color2'}>
...
</svg>
)
}
```

and then tried using this into my **Nav.tsx component**

```
const Nav = [
{path : '/', icon : <NavIcon.Home isActive = {'what should I put here?'} />},
    {path : '/service', icon : <NavIcon.Service isActive = {} />}
]

return (
<NavLink to ={path} key ={path} className = {({isActive}) => isActive ? 'class1' : 'class2'}>
{icon}
</NavLink>
)
```

*"My main aim is to change the 'fill color' of the svg wrapped around NavLink , based on whether the NavLink is active or not"*

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `NavLink` component taking a function prop on the `className` and `style` props, the `children` prop can also take a function and is passed the `isActive` property.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/nav-link)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     LinkProps,
>     "className" | "style" | "children"
>   > {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?:
>     | React.ReactNode
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => React.ReactNode);
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => string | undefined);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

Reconfigure the `Nav` array to instead hold a *reference* to the icon component you want to render and pass extraneous props to at runtime.

```
const nav = [
  { path: '/', end: true, icon: NavIcon.Home }, // only match when exactly "/"
  { path: '/service', icon: NavIcon.Service }
];
```

When mapping the `nav` array use the `children` function prop and pass the `isActive` property as a prop to the icon component.

```
nav.map(({ icon: Icon, ...props }) => (
  <NavLink key={props.path} {...props}>
    {({ isActive }) => <Icon isActive={isActive} />}
  </NavLink>
))}
```